# MCPWM on ESP32, Reset Timer value

Tags: esp32

I wrote an application using MCPWM on ESP32.

In my application I need to change the frequency of the PWM a few times.

I do this by changing:

```
MCPWM0.timer[0].period.period = 1599;
MCPWM0.channel[0].cmpr_value[0].val = 800;
```

The problem is the timer counter does not "stop", so when I change the period to a smaller value. When this value is smaller than the current timer value, it's necessary to wait the timer overflow so the new frequency is set.

I tried to stop the MCPWM before changing, but it did not help.

If I could just reset the timer value, would fix my problem.

I tried to change with:

```
MCPWM0.timer[0].status.value = 0;
```

But it did not work.

How can I reset the timer counter value?

Comment: The datasheet says the counter value is read only. And the period have shadow register. I'll do further investigation on the error.